# Can dask use s3 to store intermediate objects

Tags: amazon-s3, dask

I've been reading about `dask` and how it can work with files on `s3`. I was wondering what would happen if the worker's disk was too small to fully store the intermediate structures needed in a complex computation on incredibly large objects. Will `dask` spill temporary objects back to `s3` and use it as more temporary disk space (if given the right permissions)? Or would the computation just fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, in principle, set up a system to spill intermediates to S3, but there is no existing mechanism to automatically do this, and I have not heard of anyone having tried.